# Centering enquoted text

Tags: titles, punctuation, csquotes

I am using `csquotes` package in my document which has a title with quoted phrase. The title should be centralized, so it is nested into `center` environment. LaTeX (XeLaTeX to be more precise) handles quotation marks as a regular characters and centers title according to it. But good typography principles claim that punctuation signs should be outside the titles and not influence titles centering. Is there any solution for it?

[image: Wrong centering]

MWE for the picture above:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
      { \Large \enquote{Some long title line \\ Some long title line} }
    \end{center}  
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post the code that generated the screenshot you're showing.

Comment: Added to description.

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a code snippet which is missing a lot of potentially important information, such as which document class is in use, which relevant packages have been loaded ,and which language-related settings (if any) were chosen. If you provide this information up front, you eliminate a lot of needless guesswork and dramatically raise the likelihood that you'll get one or more useful answers.

Comment: Description has been edited again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `csquotes` provides the macros `\textquotedblright` and `\textquotedblleft`; encase them in `\phantom` statements at the end of the first line and the start of the second line, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % csquotes works better with T1 encoding...
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
       \Large \enquote{Some long title line \phantom{\textquotedblright} \\ 
              \phantom{\textquotedblleft}Some long title line} 
    \end{center}  
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example measures the width of the quote characters (via an empty `\enquote{}`). Then it puts a negative space or the quote character to the left and right of the title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand*{\negquote}{%
  \begingroup
    \settowidth{\dimen0 }{\enquote{}}%
    \leavevmode
    \kern-.5\dimen0 %
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\negquote
\enquote{Some long title line\\
Some long title line}\negquote
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The solution is not perfect:

- With long lines, the quote characters might be moved out of the text area.
- Kerning of quote characters with the following/previous text is not taken into account.